# Will Ubuntu Desktop OS get erased if I install Ubuntu server (If not how do I erase the Ubuntu desktop OS)?

Tags: dual-boot, server, system-installation

Recently I installed Ubuntu desktop and ran some tests. But now I want to run servers and I want to completely wipe the disk and the Ubuntu Desktop OS and freshly install Ubuntu Server OS. Will Ubuntu Server OS install alongside Ubuntu Desktop OS or wipe everything and install only the Ubuntu server OS?. Is there a way to wipe the Ubuntu Desktop OS and data and install the Ubuntu Server OS if it doesn't wipe the Ubuntu Desktop OS and the disk by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to erase the old install prior to installing the new one. Just boot from the LiveCD of the new Ubuntu, choose manual partitioning and make sure you choose to format the root partition.

If you have your home directory on a separate partition, you may keep it, which will preserve your documents - but, as usual, making a backup of all your data is essential before re-installing.

Comment: I'll use a USB to boot it up and I don't have anything important to backup. Thank you for the clarification.